# How to make a redirect in .htaccess for pages from different subdomains

Tags: redirect, subdomain

I'm not very advanced at programming and I need to make a 301 redirection from one specific subdomain page to another. The tricky part, at least for me, is that the pages are on two different subdomains. So far I've only managed to 301 ALL pages to the target or crashing the whole site.

I've used many, but are currently at:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^spiele.deutschedownloads.de/?DriverScanner/Diverse//download/4770$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://programme.deutschedownloads.de/?DriverScanner/Drivers/Werkzeuge-Diverse/download/4413 [L,R=301]
```

What I want to do is simply to 301 redirect

```
spiele.deutschedownloads.de/?DriverScanner/Diverse//download/4770
```

To

```
http://programme.deutschedownloads.de/?DriverScanner/Drivers/Werkzeuge-Diverse/download/4413
```

Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Are both subdomain on the same folder or separated folders?

Comment: I did not code the page, but as there are no visible folders for the subdomains I would think it's placed in the same folder.

Comment: And do you want to redirect that exact URL or all URLs with that format?

Comment: The "!" should of course not be in the Cond. The Rule seems to work fine, when I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^spiele\.deutschedownloads\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^DriverScanner/Diverse//?download/4770/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://programme.deutschedownloads.de/?DriverScanner/Drivers/Werkzeuge-Diverse/download/4413 [R=301,L]
```

First condition matches the domain in case they are both on the same root folder.

Second condition matches the query string.

If both conditions are OK it redirects.